# Copy task in Grunt with uglify

Tags: gruntjs, copy

Basicly what I'm trying to do is set up a task which will copy everything a folder contains to a folder above it in Grunt. So a 'tmp' folder is created and I want the files within that folder to be copied to the dist folder. This is what I'm currently trying but it seems to ignore the configuration.

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    'use strict';
    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        uglify: {
            options: {
                mangle: true,
                compress: {
                    drop_console: true,
                    dead_code: false,
                    unused: false
                }
            },
            files: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: "<%= ref.staging%>",
                src: ["**/*.js", '!test/**', '!test_local.html'],
                dest: "<%= ref.process%>"
            }
        },
        copy: {
            dist: {
                src: "dist/tmp/**",
                dest: "dist/"
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('@sap/grunt-sapui5-bestpractice-build');
    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'clean',
        'uglify',
        'copy'
    ]);

};
```

Comment: What is the content of tmp folder? directories or files?

Comment: an minified/ uglified version of the app, so both

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
 copy: {
        files: {
            src: ["dist/tmp/**"],
            dest: "dist/"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does not seem to be working aswell, it kinda looks like it ignores the configuration and just does a copy from the webapp folder into the dist folder. Looks like it can't read the src path.

Comment: How are you starting the task?

Comment: grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'copy'
]);

Comment: I mean, in the prompt what are you calling? Can you provide the gruntfile.js anyway in your question?

Comment: Added the gruntfile in the post, I use the build function in the SAP Web IDE multi-cloud platform.